# Using REST API to find a community user's last activity (question or comment)

Tags: soql, community, rest-api, feedcomment

I'm very new to Salesforce and trying to use the REST API to find which users were active on a community on a particular day.

For example, which users posted a question or an answer today (Aug-14-2020)?

I've managed to find a list of questions asked, by querying *UserFeed* (or *FeedItem*) using the following:

```
myServer/services/data/v48.0/query?q=SELECT+CreatedById+FROM+UserFeed+WHERE+CreatedDate+>+2020-08-13T00:00:00z+AND+CreatedDate+<+2020-08-15T00:00:00z+AND+Type+=+'QuestionPost'
```

But for comments, it's not so simple. I seem to need to query the object *FeedComment*

```
myServer/services/data/v48.0/query?q=SELECT+CreatedById+FROM+FeedComment+WHERE+CreatedDate+>+2020-08-13T00:00:00z+AND+etc
```

...but the API response is that querying *FeedComment* is only supported for admin users. I'm not meant to be an admin and so, quite rightly, our IT folks don't want to promote my account.

I tried using the Bulk API instead:

```
/services/data/v48.0/jobs/query
```

...but the same issue applies; I need to be an admin.

***So, if anyone knows of a workaround for this, I'd be grateful to hear it.***

Perhaps I don't need full admin privileges (just some additional query permission?) or perhaps there is another object or API command I can use? For example, I looked at the *User* object, but don't see anything useful except for *LastLoginDate*; but that doesn't prove a user was active, and in any case, they could have posted on the 14th after logging in on the 13th.

I just need to know which users posted to the community in a particular time period.

*ps: not that it matters, but why does FeedComment need admin permission?*